# How to pass string args to method in obj-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode

My method is look like this

```
+ (NSString *)textByPrefLang:(NSString*)Col:(NSString*)prefLang:(NSString*)tag {
 return something;
}
```

How do I call that from another class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**in .h file:**

```
+ (NSString *)textByPrefLang:(NSString*)Col withPrefLang:(NSString*)prefLang withTag:(NSString*)tag;
```

**In Implementation .m Class**

```
+ (NSString *)textByPrefLang:(NSString*)Col withPrefLang:(NSString*)prefLang withTag:(NSString*)tag {
 return something;
}
```

**When you call.**

```
NSString* message = [MyClass textByPrefLang:@"col" withPrefLang:@"en" withTag:@"tag"];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as easy as this:

1.) Import the class so it's available to you.

```
#import "YourClass.h";
```

2.) Call the method like this:

```
NSString *response = [YourClass textByPrefLang:@"aString" Col:@"anotherString" prefLang:@"andAgainAString"];
```

The returned value will now be saved in the `response` variable.

I hoped this helped you.

Sandro Meier